# Remove / from www.example.com/

Tags: urls, htaccess, site-url, home-url

Whenever I type my domain, example: `www.example.com` there is a forward slash that automatically appears in Firefox. Example: `www.example.com/`

How can I remove this?

Comment: Do you mean on your site's settings page or in your browser's address bar? I don't think the '/' matters though. Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: You can go to settings > permalinks and remove the trailing slash there, other than that you can edit the .htaccess. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558234/remove-trailing-slash-using-htaccess-in-wordpress) for more information

Comment: Note that `example.com/` and `example.com` are the same URL, and Google Chrome will even auto-remove the `/` if you type that address in the address bar. This is unlikely to be a WP thing and is probably a browser thing

Comment: @Buttered_Toast The OP is talking about the slash at the **start** of the URL-path, immediately after the hostname, not the trailing slash at the end of the URL-path, as discussed in that linked question.

Comment: You can't remove the slash at the **start of the URL-path** (following the hostname). See the following related question on the Webmasters stack: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35643/is-trailing-slash-automagically-added-on-click-of-home-page-url-in-browser

Comment: thanks everyone for your responses. i think @Tom J Nowell may be right. I tried using chrome and the slash disappeared. but in fire fox which is the default browser i use it's still there, even when i hover over the tab it says www.mydomain.com/ I guess I will just live with it.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a WordPress thing, this is a browser/HTTP thing. Firefox may be showing the `/` as part of a setting, but `example.com` and `example.com/` are the same URL.

This Q on webmasters goes into more detail as to why this is the case:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35643/is-trailing-slash-automagically-added-on-click-of-home-page-url-in-browser